Default Value/Hint Text for google sheets cells
I am trying to add default values/hint texts to cells across multiple columns.  I found this solution that would work for one column:
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/default-values/
If I make my array ={"","test","test"} it shows the default text in the next 2 columns, but once one of the columns gets overwritten, then the other default text will disappear.  My sheet has data across the columns referencing the date, so there will be constant additions to the number of columns.  Is there a way to create this default value using arrays or some other method that would apply the values across variable number of columns?  Each days worth of data is contained within 2-4 columns, is it possible to have a pattern instead of a singular default value?  Such that in each day of 4 columns, the default value would appear as "test A", "test B", "test C", "test D", then repeat for as many days added to the sheet?  Then when text is added to a certain cell, all other cells would remain with their default text?  Thank you for your help!

Please [edit] your post to include a formatted text table with your sample data, your current output, and your desired output.

The post that you were referencing is only just a work around and only applies to one column (as you would be hiding the helper column). This is not possible for multiple columns if you plan on using Google Sheets formula. However, you may use the simple trigger onEdit with the help of Google Apps Script to set the default value of blank cells.

Yes I would like multiple cells throughout multiple columns and rows to show a overwritable default value.  When the cell is cleared out, it should show that default value again.  Such as in a textbox showing "First Name" or "Last Name" and when you start typing the text disappears and when you clear the text out, "First Name" reappears.  Thank you

Could you clarify whether you're asking for a default value or a hint? If you're referring to a hint, then I recommend following God of Biscuit's suggestion.

If it's explicitly a hint that you want to display in columns (i.e. as placeholder for a blank cells, not as an overwritable default value), converting your sheet to a table using Format/Convert to table may be an option as you can then use the 'Show placeholders' option within the    Table header menus to show placeholder text for each cell within the selected column. The nature of the placeholder text depends on the column type and header; for instance, to show 'test A' as the placeholder you would need to set the column type to text and the column header itself to 'test A'.

Google Apps Script set the default value of blank cells
Inline with @PatrickdC on simple trigger onEdit using Google Apps Script. Since you would like multiple cells throughout multiple columns and rows to show an over writable default value.
you may try this approach
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const patterns = ["Test A", "Test B", "Test C", "Test D"];
  const numColumns = 4;

  const numRows = range.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range.getNumColumns();

  for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      const cell = range.offset(row, col);
      const cellValue = cell.getValue();

      if (cellValue === "") {
        const colIndex = cell.getColumn() - 1;
        const patternIndex = colIndex % numColumns;

        cell.setValue(patterns[patternIndex]);
        cell.setBackground('#d3d3d3'); // Light gray background
        cell.setFontColor('#000000'); // Black font color
      }
    }
  }
}

function setDefaultValues() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const patterns = ["test A", "test B", "test C", "test D"];
  const numColumns = 4;
  const startRow = 1;
  const startCol = 4;
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

  for (let row = startRow; row <= lastRow; row++) {
    for (let col = startCol; col <= lastCol; col++) {
      let currentValue = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();

      if (currentValue === "") {
        let pattern = (col - 1) % numColumns;
        sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue(patterns[pattern]);
      }
    }
  }
}

Sample Output
The highlighted column is the default value

once you delete or erase cells this should be the output

Reference

getLastRow()

getLastColumn()

getNumRows()

getNumColums()


Note: Please review the result to confirm if it meets your expectations. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.
